# AngularJS $scope Not Updating in Safari Until Force Resize

Tags: angularjs, safari, ionic-framework

**Quick Video Of Issue:** [DropBox Share Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1tnc1nu4qnki3n/safari_issue.mov?dl=0)

**Description:**
I have been experiencing some weird behavior from Safari when rendering content I fetch using `restangular` in `<ion-content>` tags.

As is seen in the video, the content is pulled - as logged in the console, however it only renders in Safari when I re-adjust the screen size. On the other hand, in Chrome, this renders without an issue.

**Dependencies Installed:**

- restangular
- ui-router

Anyone have an idea of what might be causing this behavior?! Thanks

Comment: Saw briefly an error appearing in the console above the html. Can you share that in the question?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Have you been able to solve this?